# Alter GET variable in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a wordpress self-hosted website, with the standard .htaccess settings:

In the website, I have a page called "animalpage". Using my rewrite settings, it is shown in the address bar as http://www.example.com/animalpage.

I am using a custom page template and am processing some things, which include the use of GET variables. For instance:

`if (isset($_GET=['word'])) { echo $_GET['word]; }` So, http://www.example.com/animalpage?word=cat will display "cat".

The problem I have is rewriting the URL so that it can look like: http://www.example.com/animalpage/dog, still being able to access "dog" as the GET variable.

I am not too good with mod_rewrite rules to begin with, but working from within a `wordpress` installation is throwing me an extra curveball.

Does anyone know what I need to add to my `.htaccess` to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Old version:

```
RewriteRule ^animalpage/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ animalpage?word=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Revisited:

```
RewriteRule ^animalpage/([^/])/?$ animalpage?word=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: The above solution might have worked if it was not wordpress. Here is the .htaccess file: `#Use PHP 5.4
# Use PHP54 as default
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
#<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
#    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php54/lib
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^animalpage/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ animalpage?word=$1 [NC,QSA]`

Comment: I have rewritten the answer, let me know if it helps.